# Find gender of employees from their SSN

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I should find gender of employees from their (SSN).and theory is , if the last number of SSN is even (0,2,4,6,8) gender is **woman** or/else if the last number of SSN is odd (1,3,5,7,9) gender is **man**.


SSN of employees look like this in my DataBase ,for ex : 1111112020 or 22222231 - and column name is XX and datatype is nvarchar(30).

The sql i wrote look like this to find out gender of employees and when i executed query i get NULL. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @Mand char(5) = '1,3,5,9,7'
DECLARE @Woman char(5) = '0,2,4,6,8'
DECLARE @Gender char (1)

SELECT (
CASE 
WHEN  right(rtrim(SSN),1) = @Mand THEN 'MAN'
WHEN right(rtrim(SSN),1) = @Woman THEN 'Woman'
ELSE NULL 
END) as gender
FROM U  
WHERE I = XXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use strings and `in` that way.  Just use the explicit list in the query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('1', '3', '5', '7', '9') THEN 'MALE'
             WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('2', '4', '6', '8', '0') THEN 'FEMALE'
        END) as gender
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE CustomerId = 214;
```

Alternatively, you could use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN rtrim(SSN) LIKE '%[13579]' THEN 'MALE'
             WHEN rtrim(SSN) LIKE '%[24680]' THEN 'FEMALE'
        END) as gender
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE CustomerId = 214;
```

I should note that I am not aware that gender is assigned this way for US social security numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your SSNs are guaranteed valid (i.e. only contain digits), then the expression `RIGHT(SSN,1)%2` (or `RIGHT(RTRIM(SSN),1)%2` if there's extra space at the end) will return `0` for females and `1` for males. There's no need for complex string searching when things have been set up to make maths easy.

You can then optionally put that in a `CASE` if you want to, e.g.

```
CASE RIGHT(SSN,1)%2
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Female'
    ELSE 'Male'
END
```

Comment: Tnx for help Damien

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ie nvarchar(30)
SET @ie = '1111112020'
SELECT (
CASE 
WHEN  right(rtrim(@ie),1) IN ('1','3','5','9','7') THEN 'MAN'
WHEN  right(rtrim(@ie),1) IN ('0','2','4','6','8') THEN 'Woman' 
END ) as gender
```

Comment: tnx for help George